# PHP multidimensional array, getting specified data only through 1 foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have two-dimensional array `$id[][]` and i'm accessing data by using two foreach loops

```
    foreach ($id as $index=>$val)
{

    foreach ($val as $ind=>$id_val)
{
...

}

}
```

but how to do that without first **foreach**, so looping process would start and end on specified index, for example  `$id[1]["and now looping with foreach second dimension"]`. Number of records on second dimension may differ.

How to achieve that, like in other programming languages with just simply putting index of 1st dimension and beginning loopiing on second only ?

Comment: `foreach ($id[1] as $index => $val)` ...

Comment: Thanks ;d Omg, I was trying some voodoo tricks and that was so easy to do.